# How to check cell is selected in UItableview for image display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

My application is navigation base. I have  UITableViewController.when i tap a cell i need to display check mark in left side of selected cell for  indication of cell is selected. For example 2 cell . First cell  is selected i need to indicate cell is selected for check mark. if i select second cell i need to disable first cell check mark  and i need to show check mark in second cell.how to check cell selection .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this. In your *cellForRowAtIndexPath* delegate method put the following code.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    ...
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark"]];
    ... 
}

[[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];

if (indexPath.row == selectedRow) { 
    [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
}
```

Have a integer variable named *selectedRow* and in your *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* delegate method include the following code,

```
...
selectedRow = indexPath.row;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Make sure you initialize    ,

```
selectedRow = -1;
```

in *init* method or somewhere where it will be initialized before the table view loads.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look [here](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/). Or just google for accessoryView, that's what you have to set.