# How to update custom image if table cell is selected outside controller

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need to update image in Firstviewcontroller if  cell is selected in tableviewcontroller. 
My application  Navigation base . Firstviewcontroller contains button event.  tap on button i am firing tableview. In tableview i am selecting cell and updating checkmark in left side , It is working fine . My question is when cell is selected same time i need to update different  custom image in viewcontroller for indicating cell is selected. [With ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453413/how-to-check-cell-is-selected-in-uitableview-for-image-display) i got image cell selecting in inside of tableview.

```
here it is Appdelegate

    @interface FertilityAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
    {
        Fertility *updateImage;

    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) Fertility *updateImage;

    @implementation
    @synthesize updateImage;



    @interface Fertility : UIViewController
    {
        UIImageView *imgView;
        FertilityAppAppDelegate *Appdelegate;
    }

    @property(nonatomic,retain) FertilityAppAppDelegate *Appdelegate;
    @property (nonatomic, retain)  UIImageView *imgView;


Viewcontroller for image update

    @implementation Fertility
    @synthesize imgView,Appdelegate;


    - (void)viewDidLoad 
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        Appdelegate = (FertilityAppAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    }

    - (void)changeImg:(UIImage*)image
    {

        imgView.image = image;
    }

    - (void)assignObjToTableViewClass
    {

        Appdelegate.updateImage = self;
    }

 Tableview controller 

    @interface Menstruation : UITableViewController 
   {

        FertilityAppAppDelegate *Appdelegate;

    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) FertilityAppAppDelegate *Appdelegate;


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath 
    {

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];
        [Appdelegate.updateImage changeImg:image];


        selectedRow = indexPath.row;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       {

             static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                if (cell == nil)
             {   

                    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
              [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tick.png"]];

              }


             [[cell imageView] setHidden:YES];

             if (indexPath.row == selectedRow) 
             {

              [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
             }


             NSString *cellValue = [MenstruationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             cell.text = cellValue;
             return cell;

      }
```

[image]

How to display in Firstviewcontroller. the above image is Button  with  red color bar in bottom of button.
When i click this button in Firstviewcontroller firing for Menstruation table view, same time i need to update image bar to Firstviewcontroller.

Comment: proper formatting would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to change the image in the another view controller then you need to assign the image in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

For that you need to access the specific view controller object(that is already using not the new one).

There are no tutorials, for these type of things.

I will send some code, please follow like that.

First of all you have to declare ImgViewController class object in the AppDelegateClass. Then only you can use.

Then use the following code. I have written this code for understanding.

```
@interface ImgViewController : UIViewController{
      UIImageView *imgView;
      AppDelegateClass *delegate;
}

@implementation ImgViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad{

     delegate = (AppDelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
     delegate.imageViewControllerObj = self; // Or you can call the method 
     //[self assignObjToTableViewClass];
}

 - (void)changeImg:(UIImage*)image{

     imgView.image = image;
}

 - (void)assignObjToTableViewClass{

    delegate.imageViewControllerObj = self;
}

@end

@interface TableViewControllerClass : UIViewController{
      AppDelegateClass *delegate;

}

@implementation TableViewControllerClass

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
         UIImage *image = //Give what ever image you want to change
         [delegate.imageViewControllerObj changeImg:image];

}


@end
```

Regards,

Satya

Comment: I need to update every time new image if different cell selected . post me some sample or tutorial

Comment: oh sorry, that is sharedApplication. "d" missed

Comment: Build and run is successful. and it is crash  . good experience  now. Here - (void)changeImg:(UIImage*)image method is updating image from tableview  to viewcontroller.if i need to  change my image of button  with id  Appdelegate.updateImage.Menstruation_Button=imgView.image; there is no update my image.

Comment: you can change the image of a button like this; [Appdelegate.updateImage.Menstruation_Button setBackgroundImage:imgView.image forState: UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: NO update my button image ,wheni edit changeImag. - (void)assignObjToTableViewClass method  when it  call

Comment: I have edited added code in the viewDidLoad method. In that you can call that assignObjToTableViewClass other than one statement. And the changeImg method will call when you click on any cell.

Comment: Ok. But there is No update of my image from tableview to image controller . when asssign Image to Id of changeImg

Comment: are you using this code in a sample App or in your project? if ans is sample app then send the code, I will check that will send to you

Comment: You have to initialize the imageViewController object in the appDelegate class. write the following code ImgViewController *imageViewController = [[ImgViewController alloc] init];

Comment: Included appDelegate header Fertility *updateImage; but no effect

Comment: Add this "Fertility *updateImage = [[Fertility alloc] initWithNibName:@"Fertility" bundle:nil];"  line in the  application didFinishLaunch method

Comment: I already tried, i am not understand me including header file and didFinishLaunch .  there is no effect at all.

Comment: I am not saying to include header file in the AppDelegate, include the statement that I provided. And can you send the recent code through your mail to my mail? So that I can edit and resend to you.

Comment: the first statement of reply add imageobject to appdelegate. i included .h file to image object. This obeject only using all class as global. If add Fertility *updateImage = [[Fertility alloc] initWithNibName:@"Fertility" bundle:nil]  didfinishLaunch , it should be local , not able to access  in other class.  , Ok. let add didfinishlaunch to image object , it should be errror after removing header file .i am not understand, if you have mail id  send me

Comment: "satyaprasad.developer@gmail.com" this is my mail id; send me the latest code.

Comment: great help ..I accepted this answer and put vote. Thanks Satya.  I will upload demo for this question  answer ..tomorrow.