# Change an image when UITableViewCell is selected

Tags: iphone, uitableview, customization

I have a `UITableViewController`, In that I added a `UIImageView` to those cells. This `UIImageView` is in a custom TableViewCell. So my question is how to change this image when i select the row using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` `delegate` method. I tried, it is showing image on tableviewcell but after clicking this image is not changing. How to resolve this?

here is my code -

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

             MantrasListCell *customCell = [tableView 
             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

               if (customCell == nil) 
               {
                  customCell = [[MantrasListCell 
                  alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
               }

         customCell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"];

         return customCell;
      }

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
    MantrasListCell *customCell = (MantrasListCell*)[tableView          
                              cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    customCell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"];        
     }
```

Comment: please explain the question .!!

Comment: Good....at last you filled those dots...now this looks like a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link will explain you. All you need to do is rather than hidden you can set image accordingly.

[How to check cell is selected in UItableview for image display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453413/how-to-check-cell-is-selected-in-uitableview-for-image-display)